# How to set Android clock to a future time?

Tags: android, clock

I need to test an App on and Android where the event it going to occur in the future as part of a campaign schedule.  I do not have access to the code and I cannot alter the input data (schedule) for the test, therefore, I need to set the clock to some future date and see if the campaign event gets triggered.

Any way to force the time on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Date & Time

then un-check "Automatic"--
this will allow you to set the date to the future

Comment: My test device is Eclair -- I don't have "Automatic" as a setting.  All that I have is "Use 24-hour format" or "Select date format." I have read elsewhere that this is not possible unless I build the OS and have that permission from my OS.

Answer (score 0):

I found an option on the Eclair Emulator to change the date and time -- which is definitely NOT in my LG 670 device nor other Androids among my colleagues (mostly Jelly Bean or Ice Cream devices).

NOTE: I have not looked in the settings for other OS versions of emulators.